# can constructors have bufferedReader objects in java

Tags: java, constructor, bufferedreader

In C++ its possible to have a default stream like

```
class c
{
 public:
  c(istream fin =cin):fin(fin){}


}
```

Similary can I do this in java or is this wrong practice.Or is there a better way of doing this? I want to choose between reading from the console and reading from a file.

```
class c
{ 
    c()
    { BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    }
   c(int i)
   {  FileReader f=new FileReader(path);
      BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(f);

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not even sure that's possible in C++.

Answer (score 3):

"Yes they can".

However, I think most would advise *doing as little as possible* in the constructor. (And I suspect many would also argue that *a constructor should not fail*, excepting perhaps bad input). The constructor doesn't necessarily have to be the consumer. For instance, see how the [Scanner class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) works. Also the [Closeable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) interface is handy to help manage resources.

Happy coding.

Comment: +1. I was trying to figure out how to say this. You hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly do that in Java. You might need to do something about possible IOExceptions being thrown. However, a better approach might be to define a constructor that takes a `Reader`, so you could instantiate an instance using any data source:

```
class C {
    C(Reader rdr) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(rdr);
    }
}
```

(By the way, Java coding conventions are that class names begin with upper case letters.)

Comment: Thanks a lot...I also want to know if this is good software engineering practice since I didn't see bufferedreader objects being used within constructors as much when I tried to look it up

Answer (score 0):

> I also want to know if this is good software engineering practice since I didn't see bufferedreader objects being used within constructors as much when I tried to look it up

I would say that it is not good design to fundamentally join the "concerns" of parsing and constructing in an API.  This is particularly important if the class is a general purpose one; i.e. one that is likely to be used / reused in different contexts.

However, provided that such a constructor is a really "convenience overload" for other more fundamental API methods / constructors that do the construction and parsing tasks, there is nothing wrong with it:

```
public Foo(Reader reader) {
    this();
    this.load(reader);
}

public Foo() {
    ...
}

public void load(Reader reader) {
    ...
}
```

I would use `Reader` rather than `BufferedReader` as the argument type.  Some use-cases don't need the buffering of a `BufferedReader`, and if your class is using the limited parsing capabilities of `BufferedReader`, you shouldn't be exposing that implementation detail in your API methods ... all things being equal.  (But pragmatics could dictate otherwise.)

If you need to use a BufferedReader internally, and you are worried about the (small) cost of an unnecessary filter in the output chain, do this:

```
public void load(Reader reader) {
    BufferedReader br = (reader instanceof BufferedReader) ?
            (BufferedReader) reader : new BufferedReader(reader);
}
```

---

Re your updated example:

Hard-wiring `System.in` or a file name in the class is bad design.  It makes the code too inflexible. A simple configuration change to read the data from somewhere else will entail a code change ... and probably a code search to find all of the *other* places where the paths, etc have been hard-wired.

Comment: If you're going to recommend calling a method from the constructor, it should be pointed out that it is dangerous to call a method that can be overridden in subclasses. See [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=20521} for a simple explanation of what problems this can cause.